# Import custom libraries into main project without breaking NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a bunch of *personal* libraries I reuse. These are kept in their own separate git repositories:

```
\Libs.Motors
\Libs.ComputerVision
\Libs.*
```

These each rely upon NuGet packages such as log4net.

I want to be able to copy specific release versions of these libraries into my projects.

```
\DestructoRobot
    \Libs.Motors
    \Libs.ComputerVision
    \MainProject

    DestructoRobot.sln
```

This appears to break when a particular NuGet package has differing versions in the `\Libs.*` compared to the solution's `MainProject`.

```
\DestructoRobot
    \packages
        \log4net.2.0.5

    \Libs.Motors
        \packages
            \log4net.1.9.2

    \MainProject
```

How do I ensure that NuGet works smoothly when copying over projects and continues to use old package references?

What is the recommended way of structuring this?

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove strict dependency on your libraries and/or main project. i.e. add allowedVersions to your libraries and/or main project